# What is a good way of Hiding mysql2 password when deploying with capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, deployment, capistrano

So, here is my capistrano file

```
load 'deploy/assets'
require "bundler/capistrano" 
set :application, "XXXXXX"
set :repository,  "XXXXXX"

set :scm, :git # You can set :scm explicitly or Capistrano will make an intelligent guess based on known version control directory names
# Or: `accurev`, `bzr`, `cvs`, `darcs`, `git`, `mercurial`, `perforce`, `subversion` or `none`
set :repository , "XXXXXX"

role :web, "XXXXXX"                          # Your HTTP server, Apache/etc
role :app, "XXXXXX"                          # This may be the same as your `Web` server
role :db,  "XXXXXX", :primary => true # This is where Rails migrations will run
#role :db,  "your slave db-server here"

set :user, 'root'
set :use_sudo, false
set :deploy_to, "/var/www/#{application}"
set :deploy_via, :remote_cache
set :normalize_asset_timestamps, false

# if you want to clean up old releases on each deploy uncomment this:
# after "deploy:restart", "deploy:cleanup"

# if you're still using the script/reaper helper you will need
# these http://github.com/rails/irs_process_scripts

# If you are using Passenger mod_rails uncomment this:
namespace :deploy do

  task :start do ; end
  task :stop do ; end
  task :restart, :roles => :app, :except => { :no_release => true } do
    run "touch #{File.join(current_path,'tmp','restart.txt')}"
  end
end
```

Now when i run `cap deploy` i get an error

```
Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

I am assuming thats because my database.yml file is

```
development:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/development.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/test.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

production:
    adapter: mysql2
    encoding: utf8
    database: XXXXX
    username: root
    password: 
    socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
```

Now since i have a public github account. I dont want to pass in my password and publish it to a github. And if I dont pass in the password i am unable to deploy the app.

What is a good way to handle this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend the following:

1. Move `config/database.yml` to `config/database.yml.sample` in your repo
2. Remove any sensitive information in `config/database.yml.sample`, such as passwords, and
   commit the "sample" config file to your repo.
3. Add `config/database.yml` to your `.gitignore` file, so it cannot be committed to the repo
4. On your server, **manually** copy `config/database.yml.sample` to `config/database.yml` in your `shared/` directory that Capistrano creates for you. This should be done **after** you run the `cap deploy:setup` command, which creates the top-level `shared` and `releases` directories. This should just be done once, manually, when setting up your application.
5. In `shared/config/database.yml` on the server, fill in the **actual** DB details, including passwords. `chmod` the file so it isn't readable by those who should not have access.
6. Add the following to your deploy script:

   ```
   namespace(:customs) do
      task :symlink_db, :roles => :app do
       run <<-CMD
         ln -nfs #{shared_path}/config/database.yml #{release_path}/config/database.yml
       CMD
     end
   end
   after "deploy:update_code", "customs:symlink_db"
   ```

Comment: after `cap deploy:setup` there aint any config folder in the shared directory. Is it ok if i leave the database.yml in the root of shared? and adjust the symlinks accordingly?

Comment: You may need to manually create `shared/config` too, or you could create a similar Capistrano recipe to the one I showed above to `mkdir -p #{shared_path}/config`. I recommend matching the relative paths, for clarity, but you could also just have it in the root of `shared` if that's easier

Comment: hi, i made some changes to the app and was trying to deploy again. But now it says `No such file or directory - /var/www/XXXX/releases/20130313094722/config/database.yml`

Comment: Did the last step above, the `customs:symlink_db` task happen after `deploy:update_code` ran? You can pass `-n` to `cap` to "dry-run" the commands and see what order they're running in to.

Comment: For capistrano 3 this is much easier: set :linked_files, %w{config/database.yml config/config.yml}. See https://semaphoreapp.com/blog/2013/11/26/capistrano-3-upgrade-guide.html

Answer (score 5):

You'll also want to make sure that your SSH system is well secured to prevent people from logging in as your Capistrano bot. I'd suggest restricting access to password-protected key pairs.

Encrypting the .yml file on the server is useless since you have to give the bot the key, which would be stored . . . on the same server. Encrypting it on your machine is probably a good idea. Capistrano can decrypt it before sending.

or

The way I have tackled this is to put the database password in a file with read permissions only for the user I run my application as. Then, in database.yml I use ERB to read the file:

```
production:
  adapter: mysql
  database: my_db
  username: db_user
  password: <%= begin IO.read("/home/my_deploy_user/.db") rescue "" end %>
```

Comment: I use a similar method that gets the password from `ENV[SOMEDB_PW]` and configure that on the server side.  Essentially the same solution.

Comment: Using environment variables is less secure than files because files have ACLs but environment variables do not and so can be checked more easily.

Comment: Like this, shorter version `<%=IO.read(File.expand_path('~/.db')) rescue ''%>`